# Regresar al input

Tags: python

Dentro un programa con un menú tengo este trozo. Es funcional, la cosa es que necesito que en el caso de que no exista el estado que se introduce vuelva a pedir el **input**, ya que en este momento regresa al menu principal. Supongo que será algo como **while**, pero no se muy bien que modificar.

```
def contarCiudades():

    estado = str(input("\nIntroduce un estado: ")).capitalize()

    with open('states.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        for acortacion, state in reader:
            if state == estado:
                break
        else:
            print("\nNo existe ese estado, vuelve a intentarlo")
            return
    with open('cities.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        total = 0
        buscar = False
        for state, *_ in reader:
            if state == acortacion:
                total += 1
                buscar = True
            else:
                if buscar:
                    break 
        print("\nHay " + str(total) + " ciudades en "+ str(estado))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar un ciclo `while` y solo romperlo cuando se encuentre el estado en el csv:

```
def contarCiudades():
    while True:
        estado = str(input("\nIntroduce un estado: ")).capitalize()

        with open('states.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
            for acortacion, state in reader:
                if state == estado:
                    return estado
        print("\nNo existe ese estado, vuelve a intentarlo.")
```

`return` como su nombre indica hace que la función o método retorne, es decir, devuelve un objeto y termina la ejecución en ese punto de forma inmediata.

Toda función en Python debe retornar un objeto, por defecto se retorna `None`, si ningún estamento `return` es ejecutado, es decir:

```
def foo():
    print("Hola")

def foo():
    print("Hola")
    return


def foo():
    print("Hola")
    return None
```

retornan exactamente lo mismo, `None`.

Dicho objeto retornado puede ser capturado en una variable cuando se llama a la función:

```
def sumar(a, b):
    suma = a + b
    return suma  # retornamos una referencia al objeto int asociado a suma

resultado = suma(2, 3)
```

Con `result = suma(2, 3)` asociamos la referencia al entero retornada por la función gracias a `return suma` a la variable `resultado`:

> ```
> >>> print(resultado)
> 5
> ```

Como se ha comentado, en el mismo instante que se ejecuta un `return` la función termina, nada de lo que quedara por ejecutar se va a ejecutar ya.

```
def foo():
    print("Hola")
    return
    print("Nunca seré ejecutado...")
```

> ```
> >>> foo()
> Hola
> ```

Por lo tanto, al usar `return` en tu caso simplemente la función termina en ese punto, de todas formas iba a terminar justo ahí, por lo que no hay diferencia alguna.

Más que contar ciudades, tu función lo que hace es pedir un estado y validarlo, todo integrado en un menú quedaría algo así:

```
import csv


def obtener_estado():
    while True:
        estado = str(input("\nIntroduce un estado: ")).capitalize()

        with open('states.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
            for acortacion, state in reader:
                if state == estado:
                    return estado
        print("\nNo existe ese estado, vuelve a intentarlo.")

def contar_ciudades(estado):
    # Contamos, falta implementar
    numero_ciudades = 5
    return numero_ciudades

while True:
    opcion = input("1. Contar ciudades\n2. Salir\n¿Qué desea hacer?: ")
    if opcion == "1":
        estado = obtener_estado()
        num_ciudades = contar_ciudades(estado)
        print(f"El {estado} tiene {num_ciudades} ciudades.")
    elif opcion == "2":
        break
    else:
        print("No ha introducido una opción válida.")
```

---

### **Edición**

Si cómo en tu caso, lo tienes todo en una función entonces no puedes usar `return` por lo ya comentado, debes usar `break` para romper el `for` y una variable de control para el `while`:

```
def contarCiudades():
    encontrado = False
    while not encontrado:
        estado = str(input("\nIntroduce un estado: ")).capitalize()

        with open('states.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
            for acortacion, state in reader:
                if state == estado:
                    encontrado = True
                    break
            else:
                print("\nNo existe ese estado, vuelve a intentarlo")

    with open('cities.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        total = 0
        buscar = False
        for state, *_ in reader:
            if state == acortacion:
                total += 1
        print(f"\nHay {total} ciudades en {estado}")

contarCiudades()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero ahora el problema es que a posteriori dentro de esa misma función hay otra en la que la consola realiza otra función, e al modificar el código ahora ya no realiza dicha función.

Comment: `while True:

        estado = str(input("Introduce un estado: ")).capitalize()

        with open('states.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for short_name, state in reader:
                if state == estado:
                    break
            else:
                print("No existe ese estado")
                return

        with open('cities.csv') as csvfile:
        ...`

Comment: Osea no se si de alguna manera puedo pasarte el programa entero, son 130 lineas de código, y en el menú hay 4 opciones, para que me explique mejor.

Comment: Hola, mira mi última edición, al final de todo dejo un ejemplo más completo que creo que es algo como lo que buscas.

Comment: He reformulado la pregunta y el código, para explicarme mejor. Lo que pasa que al introducir un estado válido me va bien, pero si no es así regresa al menú principal en lugar de volver a pedir el input. Donde debo introducir el while?

Comment: Mira la nueva edición, al final de todo, el while envuelve lo mismo, pero debes modificar cómo rompes el ciclo.

Comment: Listo, muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Deberias incluir todo el codigo en un `while`, que utilice un flag para determinar si se encontró ese estado (la primera vez lo seteas en `False`, para que al menos revise una vez). El `return` retorna la ejecución al código que llamó a esa función. Sólo necesitas determinar el valor del flag al finalizar la lectura del archivo.

```
def contarCiudades():

    estadoEncontrado = False
    while not estadoEncontrado:
        estado = str(input("\nIntroduce un estado: ")).capitalize()

        with open('states.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
            for acortacion, state in reader:
                if state == estado:
                    estadoEncontrado = True
                    return

        estadoEncontrado = False
        print("\nNo existe ese estado, vuelve a intentarlo.")
```

Comment: No me funciona, he añadido una modificación al código en la pregunta. No se donde meter el while, ya que he intentado de diversas formas pero me da fallos o acabo modificando alguna cosa

Comment: En tu codigo, debes crear un while para el flag "buscar", que es el que seteas segun encuentras el estado o no. Deberia cubrir practicamente todo el codigo de la funcion, como en mi ejemplo.